# Error in create list of the images new names

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, function

I have code that calculates NDVI and then give each image name based on the date.I want to create list after that that will contain the names-dates of each image, but I keep getting the following error message:

> timeStartsNDVI.size is not a function

it's important to mention that the code works and it display my images with th e new names but doesn't create the list I want.

This is the relevant code part:

```
var timeStartsNDVI =filterNDVI
  .distinct('system:time_start')
  .limit(23) // Take the first 5 images
  .aggregate_array('system:time_start');

timeStartsNDVI.evaluate(function (timeStarts, error) {
  //if (error) print('Error: ' + error);
  try {
    timeStarts.forEach(function (timeStart, i) {
      var image = filterNDVI
        .filterMetadata('system:time_start', 'equals', timeStart)
        .first();
      var toexport=image.visualize(NDVIcolor).addBands(image);      
      Map.addLayer(image, NDVIcolor, new Date(timeStart).toISOString());
      //Export.image.toDrive({
        //image: toexport.toFloat(),
        //description: 'NDVI' + i,
        //scale:20,
        //crs:'EPSG:4326',
        //maxPixels:1310361348,
         // You didn't include the geometry in the script you shared.
         // I assumed it was an ee.Geometry() - if so, geometry.geometry().bounds() wouldn't work
        // region:geometry.geometry().bounds()
        //region:geometry.bounds() 
      //});
    }); 
  } catch(e) {
    print('Error: ' + e);
  }
});


//HERE I GET THE ERROR
var list=timeStartsNDVI.size();

print(list);
```

I have read about this error but I ca't understand why GEE will nto understand this.

This is my full code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/940fb97af1cd8a092e5a6e3448470d83

My end goal: to have list variable with al the images and their name (which is the date)

**Edit:** this is what I get when I print "timeStartsNDVI":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sharing your assets it is impossible to reproduce the error.

Most likely because you do a serverside operation that returns a `ee.Object`, without specifying what it is (`ee.ImageCollection()`) `.size()` will throw errors like this.

So you could try first to print `timeStartsNDVI` and see what type of object it returns, if you get a ImageCollection you need to define it as such: `ee.ImageCollection(timeStartsNDVI)`. If that doesn't work you'll have to share the assets for us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: when I print it I get the list of the images but it doesn't really have the date, or it has the date in different form (attached image to the original post)

Comment: Can't help you if you don't share the asset or make reproducable example. The list you added is most likely dates in miliseconds.